# In SAS, is it good way to restart the ranuni from seed+1?

Tags: random, sas

I got some example code on generating random number in one data step or in different data steps. The seed increase 1 each time calling the ranuni function. Does any one know the performance of such kind of random numbers?

Example code:

```
%let seed = 12345;
data a;
  do i = 1 to 100;
  randnum = ranuni(&seed);
  output;
  end;

  do i = 101 to 200;
  randnum = ranuni(&seed+1);
  output;
  end;
run;
```

Comment: Why would you want this? If you want a sequence of random numbers that you can reproduce every run, just set the seed once. If you want the sequence to be different on every run, set the seed to a negative number. Can you provide some context?

Comment: It is an example I got to generate a new random stream. It may works if the two ranuni function in two separate data steps.

Comment: +1 to this is a terrible idea that you really, really should not do.  There's no reason changing the seed would make it any more "random" than just taking the next 100 numbers from the original seed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documentation about providing seeds to the random number functions can be found here:
http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/a001281561.htm

There's two additional issues:

1) Why would you ever want to do this?  I doubt you really need to.

2) Even if we suppose that you have a legitimate and reasoned application for such a use, what you're doing right now won't work.

Or rather, that is to say, the program will run and it will output as expected, but the ranuni function does not output numbers the way you think it does, with a continually updating seed.

If you really need to do this, you need to use something like the call ranuni or call rannor routines.   See the documentation that I linked to.

Your program as it exists currently will output random numbers from a stream initiated by the first call to ranuni, which in this case I believe, would be with a seed set to 12345.  Again, see the documentation I linked to.  It explains what it is ranuni actually does, and it also goes on to show why you probably don't want to do what it is that you're trying to do.

(edit: you can also investigate the newer RAND function).

Edit2: and if you really want to do it like you have now, you could maybe try:

```
%let seed = 12345;
data a;
  do i = 1 to 100;
  call ranuni(&seed, randnum);
  output;
  end;

  do i = 101 to 200;
      call ranuni(&seed + 1, randnum);
  output;
  end;
run;
```

Comment: Now I realized that in the same data step, the first seed decides the random stream of ranuni-like function.

Comment: How about the property of such two random streams? I mean something like independence.

Comment: From documentation, the general advice is: In practice, if you make multiple small streams with separate and randomly selected seeds, you probably will not encounter the problems that are shown (ie. non-independence.  It is always safer to create a single stream. With multiple streams, as the streams get longer, the chances of the streams overlapping increase.